# Is Sharia Law only applicable to an Islamic state?

Tags: sharia, islamic-government

I heard somewhere that the legal system an framework of Sharia Law is only applicable in an Islamic state. My questions are: Is Sharia Law only applicable to an Islamic state? If so, what defines an Islamic state?

Comment: Why not first looking up things in Wiki always? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_state. There have been a few muslim political theorists who have already discussed this topic based on their own respective scholastic persuasions.

Comment: I find there to be more concise and accurate answers on these forums. Also, if there are any other people who also want to know the answer to the question above, these forums will make it more easy and simple for them, rather than each singular person having to research it themselves. Thanks for the link though, I will be sure to check it out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand

> Is Sharia Law **only** applicable to an Islamic state?

we need to know what Sharia law is?

> Sharia, or sharia law, is the Islamic legal system[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharia) derived from commands in the basic texts of Islam, the Quran and Hadith (Source [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharia))

If you are a Muslim [you're expected](http://quran.com/33/36) to live a life as Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) and Allah told us to do, *no matter where you are*.

If I understood the definition of Sharia right, then not only Islamic countries, but Islamic communities or in other words Islamic individuals are expected to follow Sharia Laws (only after proper [counsel](http://quran.com/42/38)) and understanding of the Laws.

For sure, if you're not in an entirely Islamic environment, then, you cannot conduct matters of Justice on the non Muslims in your place. But all you can do is just apply them amongst those willing to be applied on. A small example, you cannot collect Jizya from local non Muslims in your place just because your community is an Islamic community. Sharia Laws are applied by understanding/studying the feasibility of each law from every angle.

So, in short, according to me instead of studying

> what defines an Islamic state?

Up to what extent can the Islamic Sharia Laws be made applicable in an Islamic state given a set of details about the state like size, type, environment, inter community relations etc.

As a general rule, instead of banging heads over the fore mentioned issues, people are suggested to [migrate](http://quran.com/4/100) to an Islamic state where either already all Laws are being employed to the full or can be made employed to the full.

For further explanation as why to migrate may be learned from [here](http://www.missionislam.com/knowledge/hijrah.htm).

May the creator guide us all.