# Is it a duty for able Muslim men to implement shariah in whatever country they are in?

Tags: sharia, obligation

Is it a duty for able Muslim men to implement shariah in whatever country they are in?

Brothers have told me it is obligatory.

Comment: Yes, and one part of shariah is to respect local laws and costums in non-muslim countries!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Sharia Law only applicable to an Islamic state?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24303/is-sharia-law-only-applicable-to-an-islamic-state)

Comment: The thing is rather that the understanding and implementation of sharia differ from place to place and from time to time. For instance, in sharia, going against the laws of a country you visit is forbidden, because you break the promise that you made to them when you visit their country. Muslims should not break a promise. If the country tells you that it's ilegal to eat halal meat and it's against their laws (because of the halal slaughter) then you are obligated to eat other than meat OR move to another country. If it's forbidden to pray and such then you should move and not live there.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, shariah is meant to rule the entire world.

> [22:64-65] To Him belongs everything in the heavens and everything on earth. Absolutely, Allah is the Most Rich, Most Praiseworthy. Do you not see that Allah has committed in your service everything on earth?
>
> [31:26]To Allah belongs all that is in the heavens and the earth. He
>   is the Rich, the Praised.
>
> [57:10] And what cause have ye why ye should not spend in the cause of
>   Allah?- For to Allah belongs the heritage of the heavens and the earth

Comment: [22:64-65] To Him belongs everything in the heavens and everything on earth. Absolutely, Allah is the Most Rich, Most Praiseworthy. Do you not see that Allah has committed in your service everything on earth? -- [31:26]To Allah belongs all that is in the heavens and the earth. He is the Rich, the Praised.

[57:10] And what cause have ye why ye should not spend in the cause of Allah?- For to Allah belongs the heritage of the heavens and the earth